# Dates are coming up as 'unicode' and I want to find out how many days

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views

I need to find out how many days in between two date ranges.  The problem I am having is that I am pulling the dates when I pass the form and they are coming back as `unicode` objects, therefor this (below) won't work.

```
start = data.get('start_date')
mat = data.get('maturity_date')
delta = start - mat
term_string += "%s" % (delta,)
```

When I try a print statement, the date output is `March 01, 2012` because the widget on my form converts it to that format.  I am wondering if there is a way to take these unicode strings and convert them back into a date format so I can use delta to get the # of days.

**Edit**
I am passing the information through print_form() which sends the data from the form to my function that allows me to fill a pdf with the information.

print_form from lib/tools.py

```
def print_form(client=None, data=None, investment_form=None, type="gic_application", plan=None, investment=None):
...
    if data:
        term_string = ''
    total_days = 0
    if investment:
        if investment.term_years:
            term_string += "%s" % (investment.term_years,)
            fdf += fdf_val_str("term_years", investment.term_years)
            fdf += fdf_val_str("Term", "Years")
        if investment.term_months:
            start = data.get('start_date')
            mat = data.get('maturity_date')
            delta = start - mat
            term_string += "%s" % (delta,)
            fdf += fdf_val_str("Term", "Days")
        if investment.term_days:
            total_days += investment.term_days
            term_string += "%s" % (total_days,)
            fdf += fdf_val_str("Term", "Days")
...
response = HttpResponse(fdf.encode("ISO-8859-1"), mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=form.xfdf'#% download_filename# % (statement_date, "statements")
return response
```

And these are the date fields from my forms.py

```
start_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput, required=False)
maturity_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput, required=False)
```

Comment: Which widget are you using? Please show us your form. If you fetch `start` and `mat` from `form.cleaned_data`, and they are date fields, then you should get date objects.

Comment: @Alasdair I am fetching start and mat from data.keys and using it to populate my pdf.  I have edited the question, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for updating. What is `data`? Is it just `request.POST`? If you use `form.cleaned_data`, you should get `date` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Alasdair's comment above; however, for the sake of completion:

Even if you are not using django's form processing, let's say the data were coming in from a text file, or something like that and you just want to parse the data directly without using the Form api, you can always convert datetime strings in python by using the tools in the datetime module, these are: strftime and strptime. The notation for conversion is fairly standard across several language implementations.

I worked on something not too long ago where the text file was extremelly large, but all the data was predictable and guaranteed to be error free. To insert into postgres would have added a significant amount of time using the form's api, so I was parsing directly using python, and saved several hours (these were very complex inserts and several million line items)

Regarding strftime and strptime, the docs are found here: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

All that said, I think Alasdair's comment will fix your specific problem.

Comment: +1, I was just writing something similar, you beat me to it. The answer to the question "how do I convert a unicode string to a datetime?" is `strptime`. However, in the OP's case, using Django's forms correctly should make that unnecessary.

Comment: @Alasdair I agree. Even if (as in your most recent comment) it isn't a POST dict, you can still pass the data to a Form in the form of a dictionary to a one shot Form just to keep things consistent (and to check for errors!)